# Is operation $x*y = \frac{xy}{x+y+1}$ associative?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

In Charles Pinter's A Book of Abstract Algebra, Chapter 2: Operations, Section B. Properties of Operations, Question 7 part ii, an operation * is defined on the set of real numbers:
$x * y = \frac{xy}{x+y+1} $
I need to find if it is associative, so:
$$
\begin{align*}
x*(y*z) &= x* \frac{yz}{y+z+1} \\\\
&= \frac{\frac{xyz}{y+z+1}}{x+\frac{yz}{y+z+1}+1} \\\\
&= \frac{\frac{xyz}{y+z+1}}{\frac{xy+xz+x+yz+y+z+1}{y+z+1}} \\\\
&= \frac{xyz}{xy+xz+yz+x+y+z+1} \\\\
\end{align*}
$$

Then the same answer for $(x*y)*z$. This is not the same as the answer given at the end:
[Answer at back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqZkL.png)

What have I overlooked?

Comment: To check the correctness of calculations, you can use online services like [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7B%5Cfrac%7Bxyz%7D%7By%2Bz%2B1%7D%7D%7Bx%2B%5Cfrac%7Byz%7D%7By%2Bz%2B1%7D%2B1%7D+%3D%3D+%5Cfrac%7B%5Cfrac%7Bxyz%7D%7Bx%2By%2B1%7D%7D%7Bz%2B%5Cfrac%7Bxy%7D%7Bx%2By%2B1%7D%2B1%7D)